# Power BI Microsoft SQL: Incorrect syntax near ';'. Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi

The following runs well in DataGrip. However, in Power BI, I am getting this error and do not know why:

> Microsoft SQL: Incorrect syntax near ';'. Incorrect syntax near ')'.

It was giving me another CTE error where I had to add the semicolon at the start, but this I cannot seem to figure out. Syntax looks fine.

```
  ;WITH pizzaorder AS ( 
        SELECT DISTINCT [order].id 
        FROM [order]
        LEFT JOIN order_line 
        ON order_line.order_id = [order].id 
        WHERE pizza_product_id IS NOT NULL
    ),
    
    otherproductorder AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT [order].id 
        FROM [order]
        LEFT JOIN order_line ON order_line.order_id = [order].id 
        WHERE other_product_id IS NOT NULL
    ),
    
    mostsold AS (
        SELECT TOP 10 product_name,
        SUM(quantity) AS quantity 
        FROM pizzaorder
        INNER JOIN otherproductorder ON otherproductorder.id = pizzaorder.id 
        LEFT JOIN order_line ON order_line.order_id = pizzaorder.id 
        INNER JOIN product ON product.id = order_line.other_product_id 
        GROUP BY product_name
    )
    
    SELECT TOP 10 *
    FROM mostsold 
    ORDER BY quantity DESC
```

Comment: I'm sure there is a simpler way to write the query.  You should explain what you want the query to do.  Sample data and desired results help too.

Comment: You really should start over. The multiple uses of DISTINCT has a bad smell and the use of TOP 10 without an ORDER BY clause is a logical flaw. Your schema looks very suspicious with very, VERY specific columns (other_product_id and pizza_product_id) that suggest normalization problems. Lastly the final query selects the top 10 rows from mostsold - but that cte is already limited to 10 rows. Even if your query "works" in a different tool, it is unlikely to give you correct results or consistent results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many contexts Power BI will compose your provided query with additional queries by wrapping it in a subquery.  That doesn't work with CTEs.

So you can create a view using that logic, or transform your CTEs to subqueries in the FROM clause.

But generally you shouldn't be doing that kind of query work before exposing the data to Power BI.  In Power BI you typically bring in each table separately into the Power BI Data Set.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by starting over as SMor Suggested.

Its still not perfect and the database has some flaws, but this is the solution that worked for my situation.

```
SELECT TOP 10 product_name, SUM(quantity) AS quantity 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [order].id 
    FROM [order] 
    LEFT JOIN order_line ON order_line.order_id = [order].id 
     WHERE pizza_product_id IS NOT NULL) as pizzaorder 
LEFT JOIN order_line ON order_line.order_id = pizzaorder.id 
INNER JOIN product ON product.id = order_line.other_product_id 
GROUP BY product_name 
ORDER BY quantity DESC
```